# XML and X-Link usage

Tags: xml, hyperlink, xlink

I just have a simple question: let's say I have a read only XML file, and I want to create links or make link for elements in the file. How will that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use the XHTML namespace:

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <a href="#2">link</a><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><xmp id="2">to me</xmp><pre>to click</pre>
</root>
```